# R is adding 72 rows of "NA" entries in a data frame

Tags: r

So as the title says, R is randomly adding rows of "NA" entries in a data frame. This only happens when I index into it. So a line like:

```
data[data$subject_code==1,]
```

will produce all the data I want, but with 72 rows at the end that all look like this:

```
NA.8        NA   NA             NA
```

Why is this happening?? It doesn't make any sense...there is not a single entry that has the value "NA" in the entire data frame.

Comment: Consider posting the first 5 and the last 5 rows of your data set (including any headers) and the code you are using to read it.

Answer (score 3):

No you have missing values in your data. see `is.na` or `complete.cases`. I guess you get an error because you try to check missing values using =="NA".

```
dat <- data.frame(x=cbind(NA,NA,NA,NA))
dat
  x.1 x.2 x.3 x.4
1  NA  NA  NA  NA
## this reproduce the same output
 dat[dat$x.1==1,]
   x.1 x.2 x.3 x.4
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

You should remove missing values before sub-setting, for example:

```
dat[complete.cases(dat),]
```

Or

```
dat[!is.na(dat$subject_code),]
```